# Is there any rule for integrals of the form $\int f(g′(x))g(x)dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there any rule for integrals of the form $$\int f(g′(x))g(x)\,dx.$$

Motivated by [Where is the form $f(g(x))g'(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619833/where-is-the-form-fgxgx) and [Integration of f(g(x)) by substitution, "creating" g'(x) dx term, how it works?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534360/integration-of-fgx-by-substitution-creating-gx-dx-term-how-it-works)

Comment: No. There's no reason why there should be. The one you cite is true because of the chain rule. There's no corresponding fact about differentiation to justify the one you hope for.

Comment: Maybe logarithmic derivative can give a hint: $\frac {d\log(f(x))}{d x} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why integrals of the form
$$\int f\left(g(x)\right) g'(x) \, \mbox{d}x$$
can be simplified to
$$\int f\left(u\right) \, \mbox{d}u$$
is a direct consequence of the chain rule for derivatives.

There is no simple rule (for derivatives) which would do something similar to an integrand of the form $f\left(g'(x)\right) g(x)$, so you can't expect an easy, general rule for integrands of this form.

---

For example, taking $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x) = \ln x$ would lead to
$$\int \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \ln x \, \mbox{d}x$$
which has [no elementary anti-derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sin(1%2Fx)*ln(x)+dx).